# Big O: What is the relationship between O(log(n)) with real time

Tags: data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

I've calculated the real time in millisecond for my algo.
I've plotted a graph comparing the actual time taken by my algorithm in Milli-Seconds(y-axis) to 'n'(x-axis) where n is the number of nodes in the tree I'm working on.

How do I relate this graph to O(log(n)) if my algorithm should ideally have a O(log(n)) complexity.

Comment: what is the actual question here?

Comment: The question is that in a graph with y axis as the time in milliseconds and x axis as 'n'. Can we compare the complexity of my algo with a graph log(n). @specializt

Comment: If its milli seconds...then why milliseconds? @specializt

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your algorithm is in O(log n) the graphs should make for a nice comparison. But don't plot `log n`, you need `k * log n + c` for some constants `k` and `c`.

The constant `k` describes the duration of a single step of your algorithm, whereas `c` summaries all constant  (initialization) cost.

Depending on what you want to achieve and your algorithm / implementation you might see effects like processor cache misses, garbage collection or similar stuff with increasing `n`.

Comment: Yeah! Some runs with a high 'n' seem to look erroneous @Daniel Jour

Comment: What about a graph of log(n) Vs 'time taken in Milliseconds' does it provide any insight?

Comment: @Identity1 my answer concludes that graph as well

Answer (score 1):

In case you can save `n,log(n),runtime(n)`:

[image]

You can use 3 visualization approaches (I used Excel since it is easy and fast):

1. Draw a [QQ-plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) between log(n) and your run time:
   [image]

This figure shows you the difference between the 'Theoretical' run time function and the 'Empirical' run time function. A straight line (or close) implies that they are close.

2. Draw two plots on the same graph: the horizontal axes is n, and the two functions are log(n) and the run time you obtained for each n:

[image]

3. The third analysis is the statistical approach: plot a graph where the horizontal axis is n, and the vertical axes is runtime(n). Now, add a logarithmic trend line and [Rsquare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination).

[image]

The trend line can give you the best `a`,`b` where `runtime(n)=a*log(n)+b` . The correlation between the runtime and log(n) is better as Rsquare gets higher.

Comment: Can't see the images @OBP

Comment: @Identity1 something changed?

Comment: No buddy I guess it's some isse with my network @OBP

Comment: It really demonstrate the techniques you can use, try view it with from another computer... Waiting for you to comment on it

Comment: Yeah buddy! I'll read more about it soon...I'll get this issue fixed as soon as I'm free. Thanks for the reply though, looks worth a try (Upvoted!)

Comment: @Identity1 So, did you see the graphs?  did it help? feel free to accept :)